# Detect corner point from rectangle with rounded corners

Tags: opencv

I need to solve a problem when I am detecting rectangles with rounded corners using opencv. Basically I'm using the same code sample squares.c:

```
cvFindContours( gray, storage, &contours, sizeof(CvContour), CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );
while( contours )
{
    double area=fabs(cvContourArea(contours, CV_WHOLE_SEQ));
    if(area < minimum_area || area > maximum_area) {
        contours = contours->h_next;
        continue;
    }               
    result = cvApproxPoly( contours, sizeof(CvContour), storage,
        CV_POLY_APPROX_DP, cvContourPerimeter(contours)*0.05, 0 );
    if( result->total == 4 &&
        fabs(cvContourArea(result,CV_WHOLE_SEQ)) > 1000 &&
        cvCheckContourConvexity(result) )
        {
```

With this code I can usually detect the image, but I need to adjust the image's perspective and for that I need to detect the corners of the image, how to do this and the image has rounded corners? The problem happens because the point I need not detected between points, as an example, I created the following image, where the black lines represent the points detected by the existing code and the blue dots are the ones I need?

[image]

Thank's for any help.

Comment: By "I need to solve a problem" do you mean "I want a ready OpenCV function that solves my problem" ? Your problem is solved by simple smart orderings of the black points. From there you build the four blue corners.

Comment: @mmgp ordering black points? But black points do not contain blue points!

Comment: I found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519545/automatic-perspective-correction-opencv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In OpenCV terms, first find the black rectangle by using `FindContours` with `RETR_EXTERNAL` and `CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE`. Now you find the minimal bounding box of this round rectangle by using `minAreaRect` on the points found by `FindContours`. To get the corners of this bounding box, use the function `BoxPoints` on the return (center, (width, height), rotation angle) of `minAreaRect`. Now you have the four corners of the red line you are after.

Comment: minAreaRect will actually return a rectangle and not a quadrilateral like in the red line desired result example.

Answer (score 5):

I had the issue, and none of the other answers helped. In my case i had to perspective correct datamatrices, which have a missing corner on the top right, that looks rounded on a harris detection.

In order to fix this, detect the shape any way you like, then get the convex hull of the contour. Once you have it you will have to extract the 4 longest lines (no opencv function exists, you have to make your own extraction function)
Then you simply get the intersections of the 4 lines (your own function as well) and convert it back to a matrix for perspective correction.

If your medium can be bent or your detection can have imperfections, you may want to also delete points from the contour that have high angles relative to the neighboring points, which can create deviations in the final points.

Answer (score 0):

Try scaling image to a smaller size by cvResize command and apply that code to it. Theoretically reducing image size should sharpen image corners and reduce your problem at a an expense of losing precision.

Comment: A note, this works pretty well, but you need to make sure to use a decent interpolation setting when resizing such as `cubic` not `nearest neighbor`.