# How to detect rounded rectangle using C#?

Tags: c#, image-processing, rounded-corners

I need to detect the rounded rectangle in the image in order to obtain the readings inside it. If anyone could guide me to detect the rounded rectangle it would be a great help.

I tried it with the emgu cv example but I couldn't detect the rectangles.

Comment: If there are any sample C sharp codes available to detect the rounded rectangles please post it. Thanks

Comment: Please follow the link to view the image to detect rounded rectangle http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=197681.msg1458788#msg1458788

Comment: the image posted in the arduino forum leads me to the impression that you will have lots of fun trying to automatically read the values... the water meter itself has round edges :)

Comment: But it can be done by fitting the camera closer to the meter. But somehow i need to detect the rounded rectangle. Is there any ideas to detect the readings inside it? Please help. Thanks

Comment: Actually i found Emgu CV example code for detecting the numbers. The numbers identifying part can be done but first should detect the region of the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EmguCV try using something like the Hough Transform to detect lines if it can't detect the rectangle and use the intersections to calculate the rectangle position.

This question shows some tips using OpenCV - the library EmguCV is a wrapper for.
[Detect corner point from rectangle with rounded corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14269509/detect-corner-point-from-rectangle-with-rounded-corners)