# Automatic perspective correction OpenCV

Tags: c++, ios, opencv

I am trying to implement Automatic perspective correction in my iOS program and when I use the test image I found on the tutorial everything works as expected. But when I take a picture I get back a weird result.

I am using code found in this [tutorial](https://opencv-code.com/tutorials/automatic-perspective-correction-for-quadrilateral-objects/)

When I give it an image that looks like this:

[image]

I get this as the result:

[image]

Here is what `dst` gives me that might help.

[image]

I am using this to call the method which contains the code.

`quadSegmentation(Img, bw, dst, quad);`

Can anyone tell me when I am getting so many green lines compared to the tutorial? And how I might be able to fix this and properly crop the image to only contain the card?

Comment: Your results look like garbage to me. You need to show more code. Specifically, what format are you sending `Img` as, and how are you interpreting the output lines?

Comment: Indeed very helpful !! But just few words of caution, it may not work , if business card is kept at some angle with respect to horizontal axis. in that case bounding rectangle will also be at same angle with respect to horizontal axis and accordingly corners points will be different

Answer (score 43, accepted):

For perspective transform you need,

source points->Coordinates of quadrangle vertices in the source image.

destination points->  Coordinates of the corresponding quadrangle vertices in the destination image.

Here we will calculate these point by contour process.

**Calculate Coordinates of quadrangle vertices in the source image**

- You will get the your card as contour by just by blurring, thresholding, then find contour, find largest contour etc..
- After finding largest contour just calculate [approximates a polygonal curve](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#approxpolydp), here you should get 4 Point which represent corners of your card. You can adjust the parameter `epsilon`  to make 4 co-ordinates.

[image]

**Calculate Coordinates of the corresponding quadrangle vertices in the destination image**

- This can be easily find out by  calculating bounding rectangle for largest contour.

[image]

In below image the red rectangle represent source points and green for destination points.

[image]

**Adjust the co-ordinates order and Apply Perspective transform**

- Here I manually adjust the co-ordinates order and you can use some sorting algorithm.
- Then calculate [transformation matrix](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#getperspectivetransform) and apply [wrapPrespective](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#warpperspective)

See the final result

[image]

**Code**

```
 Mat src=imread("card.jpg");
 Mat thr;
 cvtColor(src,thr,CV_BGR2GRAY);
 threshold( thr, thr, 70, 255,CV_THRESH_BINARY );

 vector< vector <Point> > contours; // Vector for storing contour
 vector< Vec4i > hierarchy;
 int largest_contour_index=0;
 int largest_area=0;

 Mat dst(src.rows,src.cols,CV_8UC1,Scalar::all(0)); //create destination image
 findContours( thr.clone(), contours, hierarchy,CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE ); // Find the contours in the image
 for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ ){
    double a=contourArea( contours[i],false);  //  Find the area of contour
    if(a>largest_area){
    largest_area=a;
    largest_contour_index=i;                //Store the index of largest contour
    }
 }

 drawContours( dst,contours, largest_contour_index, Scalar(255,255,255),CV_FILLED, 8, hierarchy );
 vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly(1);
 approxPolyDP( Mat(contours[largest_contour_index]), contours_poly[0],5, true );
 Rect boundRect=boundingRect(contours[largest_contour_index]);
 if(contours_poly[0].size()==4){
    std::vector<Point2f> quad_pts;
    std::vector<Point2f> squre_pts;
    quad_pts.push_back(Point2f(contours_poly[0][0].x,contours_poly[0][0].y));
    quad_pts.push_back(Point2f(contours_poly[0][1].x,contours_poly[0][1].y));
    quad_pts.push_back(Point2f(contours_poly[0][3].x,contours_poly[0][3].y));
    quad_pts.push_back(Point2f(contours_poly[0][2].x,contours_poly[0][2].y));
    squre_pts.push_back(Point2f(boundRect.x,boundRect.y));
    squre_pts.push_back(Point2f(boundRect.x,boundRect.y+boundRect.height));
    squre_pts.push_back(Point2f(boundRect.x+boundRect.width,boundRect.y));
    squre_pts.push_back(Point2f(boundRect.x+boundRect.width,boundRect.y+boundRect.height));

    Mat transmtx = getPerspectiveTransform(quad_pts,squre_pts);
    Mat transformed = Mat::zeros(src.rows, src.cols, CV_8UC3);
    warpPerspective(src, transformed, transmtx, src.size());
    Point P1=contours_poly[0][0];
    Point P2=contours_poly[0][1];
    Point P3=contours_poly[0][2];
    Point P4=contours_poly[0][3];


    line(src,P1,P2, Scalar(0,0,255),1,CV_AA,0);
    line(src,P2,P3, Scalar(0,0,255),1,CV_AA,0);
    line(src,P3,P4, Scalar(0,0,255),1,CV_AA,0);
    line(src,P4,P1, Scalar(0,0,255),1,CV_AA,0);
    rectangle(src,boundRect,Scalar(0,255,0),1,8,0);
    rectangle(transformed,boundRect,Scalar(0,255,0),1,8,0);

    imshow("quadrilateral", transformed);
    imshow("thr",thr);
    imshow("dst",dst);
    imshow("src",src);
    imwrite("result1.jpg",dst);
    imwrite("result2.jpg",src);
    imwrite("result3.jpg",transformed);
    waitKey();
   }
   else
    cout<<"Make sure that your are getting 4 corner using approxPolyDP..."<<endl;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will look into this in the morning.

Comment: I understand nearly all of the code, but could you explain the `squre_pts` after the if statement?

Comment: That is nothing but getting four corner points for bounding rect in the order as we consder source points.

Comment: When I threshold `thr` I don't get back the image you get back in your results mine includes some noise in the background off the card and some text on the card it self. Here is an example of a source image straight from the iOS device. http://i.imgur.com/T4wsOW8.jpg Any idea how I can fix this? It is causing the `if-statment` to return false.

Comment: Is there is adaptive threshold I could use to get similar settings since the images won't be the same each time?

Comment: @NICK Hi sorry for the late reply, In the above image it look like noisy, so it's always better to perform smooth before thresholding. Also making the value of `epsilon` higher will give you 4 Points for `approxPolyDP`, see the answer above I have edited little. And finally you need to sort source and destination points correctly using any algorithm as I done it manually in above code.

Comment: Many cool and simple ideas in only one answer e.g: "...this can be easily find out by calculating bounding rectangle for largest contour..."! Very interesting and useful instructions. Many, many thanks!

Comment: CV_AA => cv::LINE_AA in OpenCV 4

Answer (score 7):

teethe This typically happens when you rely on somebody else code to solve your particular problem instead of adopting the code. Look at the processing stages and also the difference between their and your image (it is a good idea by the way to start with their image and make sure the code works):

1. Get the edge map. - will probably work since your edges are fine
2. Detect lines with Hough transform. - **fail since you have lines not only on the contour but also inside of your card. So expect a lot of false alarm lines**
3. Get the corners by finding intersections between lines. - **fail for the above mentioned reason**
4. Check if the approximate polygonal curve has 4 vertices. - **fail**
5. Determine top-left, bottom-left, top-right, and bottom-right corner. - **fail**
6. Apply the perspective transformation.  - **fail completely**

To fix your problem you have to ensure that only lines on the periphery are extracted. If you always have a dark background you can use this fact to discard the lines with other contrasts/polarities. Alternatively you can extract all the lines and then select the ones that are closest to the image boundary (if your background doesn't have lines).