# OpenCV flood fill card edge

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using this code to attempt to find the edges of a card in an image. When I run it, it only outlines half of the cards edge.

Here is a sample of an image that I get back.

[image]

```
cvtColor(Img, bw, CV_RGB2GRAY);
Mat outerBox = Mat(bw.size(), CV_8UC1);
GaussianBlur(bw, bw, cv::Size(11,11), 0);
adaptiveThreshold(bw, outerBox, 255, ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, THRESH_BINARY, 5, 2);
bitwise_not(outerBox, outerBox);
Mat kernel = (Mat_<uchar>(3,3) << 0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0);
dilate(outerBox, outerBox, kernel);

int count=0;
int max=-1;
cv::Point maxPt;

for(int y=0;y<outerBox.size().height;y++)
{
    uchar *row = outerBox.ptr(y);
    for(int x=0;x<outerBox.size().width;x++)
    {
        if(row[x]>=128)
        {
            int area = floodFill(outerBox, cv::Point(x,y), CV_RGB(0,0,64));

            if(area>max)
            {
                maxPt = cv::Point(x,y);
                max = area;
            }
        }
    }
}
floodFill(outerBox, maxPt, CV_RGB(255,255,255));
```

The line of code in particular that is in question is `floodFill(outerBox, maxPt, CV_RGB(255,255,255));`

Can anyone tell me how I can modify my code so it fills the rest of the cards edge? The highlighted edge is not always consistent depending on the image, but at least 1/2 of the edge is filled always starting with the left side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you a guy who posted this? [Automatic perspective correction OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519545/457687)
You are doing everything all right but in a complex way. You result should be[image]. See the difference? Not in lines but in blur. I guess you just did not display your output correctly. By the way, you forgot to mention a link to the input image and show how you display the result in your code.

IT is very beneficial to look at the intermediate output of your algorithm. You can do this with just one line of code, for example:

```
imshow("blur", bw);
```

Also  don't flood fill a single channel gray image with color values like CV_RGB(0,0,64). Doing this in the loop dynamically can lead to unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks for the response I am developing for iOS. I am outputting my images by converting them to a `UIImage` then putting them on my device's screen. `_endImage = [self UIImageFromMat:outerBox];` When I show `bw` I just get a grayscale image. How did you get the result above?

Comment: I ran your code, that's how. I did this on my Mac in Eclipse and I went through all the intermediate stages with imshow("win", mat) to check what's going on. Everythig worked ok but as I mentioned you have a potentially wrong faulty code with writing color pixels in gray image that you modify and check at every loop iterations. Just use 64 instead of CV_RGB(0,0,64) and probably output every time you discover the max-area connected component if your still have a problem at your system.

Comment: Also, if you somehow cannot resolve the problem, try using opencCV findContours() function (it will hopefully be faster and will run without a loop). http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcon#cv.FindContours You can calculate the length of each contour instead of the area of your connected component to find periphery or even better create a bounding box for each contour and select the one with the largest bbox closer to the image border.

Comment: Thanks I replaced that code and still gives me a similar result, I think I'll try my OpenCV code in eclipse instead of Xcode. In Xcode it won't let me use `imshow` `imwrite`. It might be giving me some problems.

Comment: Eclipse is a good idea. Also, since you implicitly assume in your code that there is no gradient (contrast) at the background you can just start with your dilated image and move from a boundary towards the center along each row and column until you hit the periphery of your card in order to discover a set of pixels on the card border. In other words, traverse down from the top, traverse up from the bottom, traverse left from the right border and right from the left border. It is much cleaner than using Connected Components (what if there is a long spiral CC inside of a card?). Good luck.

Comment: Do you by chance have the exact code you ran to get that result? Is that result from `outerBox` or `bw`?

Comment: I believe there is an issue with the image coming from the iPhone camera, when I put in a test image such as a playing card from google images it gives me a good result. But when the image comes from the camera it does not. Do you know why this might be happening? Something off with the color space?

Comment: I output outboX of course. Did you figure why your lines arent fat? To see the difference between camera and files Check the number of channels. mat.channels ().

Comment: Both images start at 4 channels and end at 1. And it turns out I can't find out what colorspace the images are before hand. Are there any other "settings" on the `Mat` I can look at? Thanks for your help btw, just a lost high school kid haha.

Comment: is it when you read them from file? can you specify gray as a second flag (argument) of image read? see http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#cv2.imread

Comment: When I load, what I am doing is loading a `UIImage` from a file in the project, then converting it to a Mat. Loading it that way gives me good results exactly the same as yours. However when it comes from the camera I get bad results as above.

Comment: split and merge procedures of openCV can merge and split channel not to mention that you do cvtColor(Img, bw, CV_RGB2GRAY); May be you should use RGBA since you mentioned 4 channels, or add a channel arg. to avoid default settings:  cvtColor(Img, bw, CV_RGB2GRAY, 1);

Comment: The images drastically change on the adaptive threshold, when loaded the border of the card is thick, when captured borders are thin. I'm going to mess with the parameters on it.

Comment: these aren't adaptive threshold parameters. Just channels of the input array. In one case your have gray in another you have rgb or rgba.

Comment: Thanks for the response, what I meant is that when the adaptive threshold is ran is when the images change. On a loaded image the card edges are thick, and on a captured image the edges are thin.

Comment: Yes, I notice hence I wrote in my first answer "See the difference? Not in lines but in blur.” Thickness comes from dilate operation though, not thresholding.