# Perspective correction in OpenCV using python

Tags: python, opencv, perspective

I am trying to do a perspective correction of a tilted rectangle ( a credit card), which is tilted in all the 4 directions. I could find its four corners and the respective angles of its tilt but I cannot find the exact location of the coordinates, where it has to be projected. I am using cv2.getPerspectiveTransform to do the transformation.

I have the aspect ratio of the actual card (the non tilted one), I want such coordinates such that the original aspect ratio is preserved. I have tried using a bounding rectangle but this increases the size of the card.

Any help would be appreciated.[image: test image]

[image: Bounding Rectangle]

Comment: You can see the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519545/automatic-perspective-correction-opencv/22550609#22550609 might be helpful.

Comment: I have specified it in my question that I have already tried projecting it to bounding rectangle vertices, I do not get the actual aspect ratio, the breadth increases,I would post the image

Comment: Taking the vertices of the bounding rectangle would over estimate the breadth of the card

Comment: Yes that true............

Comment: Am I mistaken or doesn't that bar code encode whatever digits are fruitlessly obscured beneath it?

Comment: What about using OpenCV to detect the barcode and then applying homography to the straightened barcode?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is the way you need to follow...

For easiness I have resized your image to smaller size,

[image]

- Compute quadrangle vertices for source image, here I find out manually, you can choose edge detection, hough line etc..

> ```
>   Q1=manual calculation;
>   Q2=manual calculation;
>   Q3=manual calculation;
>   Q4=manual calculation;
> ```

- Compute quadrangle vertices in the destination image by keeping aspect ratio, here you can to take width  of card from above quadrangle vertices of source, and compute height by multiplying with aspect ratio.

> ```
>    // compute the size of the card by keeping aspect ratio.
>     double ratio=1.6;
>     double cardH=sqrt((Q3.x-Q2.x)*(Q3.x-Q2.x)+(Q3.y-Q2.y)*(Q3.y-Q2.y)); //Or you can give your own height
>     double cardW=ratio*cardH;
>     Rect R(Q1.x,Q1.y,cardW,cardH);
> ```

- Now you got quadrangle vertices for source and destination, then apply warpPerspective.

[image]

You can refer below C++ code,

```
   //Compute quad point for edge
    Point Q1=Point2f(90,11);
    Point Q2=Point2f(596,135);
    Point Q3=Point2f(632,452);
    Point Q4=Point2f(90,513);

    // compute the size of the card by keeping aspect ratio.
    double ratio=1.6;
    double cardH=sqrt((Q3.x-Q2.x)*(Q3.x-Q2.x)+(Q3.y-Q2.y)*(Q3.y-Q2.y));//Or you can give your own height
    double cardW=ratio*cardH;
    Rect R(Q1.x,Q1.y,cardW,cardH);

    Point R1=Point2f(R.x,R.y);
    Point R2=Point2f(R.x+R.width,R.y);
    Point R3=Point2f(Point2f(R.x+R.width,R.y+R.height));
    Point R4=Point2f(Point2f(R.x,R.y+R.height));

    std::vector<Point2f> quad_pts;
    std::vector<Point2f> squre_pts;

    quad_pts.push_back(Q1);
    quad_pts.push_back(Q2);
    quad_pts.push_back(Q3);
    quad_pts.push_back(Q4);

    squre_pts.push_back(R1);
    squre_pts.push_back(R2);
    squre_pts.push_back(R3);
    squre_pts.push_back(R4);


    Mat transmtx = getPerspectiveTransform(quad_pts,squre_pts);
    int offsetSize=150;
    Mat transformed = Mat::zeros(R.height+offsetSize, R.width+offsetSize, CV_8UC3);
    warpPerspective(src, transformed, transmtx, transformed.size());

    //rectangle(src, R, Scalar(0,255,0),1,8,0);

    line(src,Q1,Q2, Scalar(0,0,255),1,CV_AA,0);
    line(src,Q2,Q3, Scalar(0,0,255),1,CV_AA,0);
    line(src,Q3,Q4, Scalar(0,0,255),1,CV_AA,0);
    line(src,Q4,Q1, Scalar(0,0,255),1,CV_AA,0);

    imshow("quadrilateral", transformed);
    imshow("src",src);
    waitKey();
```

Comment: Please check this answer http://answers.opencv.org/question/23910/boundary-detection-what-function-will-be-the-best-for-this/#23916 might be helpful.

Comment: Last question if I may. Could you please show how you can get a good birdview from this image: http://imgur.com/a/v1mD0 , I tried by all means to get a proper result but this was the best I ever managed to get: http://imgur.com/a/MtseW Impossible for me to getter a better bird-eye-view than this

Comment: @LandonZeKepitelOfGreytBritn A bit off topic, but this is the best I was able to do https://imgur.com/a/jXFtD

Comment: See similar implementation and demo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZxFn5-5YLhA

Comment: CV_AA => cv::LINE_AA in OpenCV 4

Answer (score 12):

I'm writing the answer provided by @Haris in python.

```
import cv2
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('test.jpg')
rows,cols,ch = img.shape

pts1 = np.float32([[360,50],[2122,470],[2264, 1616],[328,1820]])

ratio=1.6
cardH=math.sqrt((pts1[2][0]-pts1[1][0])*(pts1[2][0]-pts1[1][0])+(pts1[2][1]-pts1[1][1])*(pts1[2][1]-pts1[1][1]))
cardW=ratio*cardH;
pts2 = np.float32([[pts1[0][0],pts1[0][1]], [pts1[0][0]+cardW, pts1[0][1]], [pts1[0][0]+cardW, pts1[0][1]+cardH], [pts1[0][0], pts1[0][1]+cardH]])

M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts1,pts2)

offsetSize=500
transformed = np.zeros((int(cardW+offsetSize), int(cardH+offsetSize)), dtype=np.uint8);
dst = cv2.warpPerspective(img, M, transformed.shape)

plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img),plt.title('Input')
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(dst),plt.title('Output')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: why the ratio is 1.6??

Comment: @CuriousG.ratio of cards dimensions.

Comment: Hi Just tried you method in python however the results are no longer the same as you example above as still some distortion present. Any idea why it may be causing a different result?

Answer (score 8):

[image]
I have a better solution which is much easy:

- The red rectangle on original image and the corners points of the rectangle are source points
- We use  `cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(src, dst)` that takes source points and destination points as arguments and returns the transformation matrix which transforms any image to destination image as show in the diagram
- We use this transformation matrix in `cv2.warpPerspective()`
  - As you can see results are better. You get a very nice bird view of the image

  ```
  import cv2
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  import numpy as np


  def unwarp(img, src, dst, testing):
      h, w = img.shape[:2]
      # use cv2.getPerspectiveTransform() to get M, the transform matrix, and Minv, the inverse
      M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(src, dst)
      # use cv2.warpPerspective() to warp your image to a top-down view
      warped = cv2.warpPerspective(img, M, (w, h), flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

      if testing:
          f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(20, 10))
          f.subplots_adjust(hspace=.2, wspace=.05)
          ax1.imshow(img)
          x = [src[0][0], src[2][0], src[3][0], src[1][0], src[0][0]]
          y = [src[0][1], src[2][1], src[3][1], src[1][1], src[0][1]]
          ax1.plot(x, y, color='red', alpha=0.4, linewidth=3, solid_capstyle='round', zorder=2)
          ax1.set_ylim([h, 0])
          ax1.set_xlim([0, w])
          ax1.set_title('Original Image', fontsize=30)
          ax2.imshow(cv2.flip(warped, 1))
          ax2.set_title('Unwarped Image', fontsize=30)
          plt.show()
      else:
          return warped, M
  im = cv2.imread("so.JPG")
  w, h = im.shape[0], im.shape[1]
  # We will first manually select the source points 
  # we will select the destination point which will map the source points in
  # original image to destination points in unwarped image
  src = np.float32([(20,     1),
                    (540,  130),
                    (20,    520),
                    (570,  450)])

  dst = np.float32([(600, 0),
                    (0, 0),
                    (600, 531),
                    (0, 531)])

  unwarp(im, src, dst, True)

  cv2.imshow("so", im)
  cv2.waitKey(0)[![enter image description here][1]][1]
  cv2.destroyAllWindows()
  ```