# How to identify space between paragraphs and draw a line between them using opencv2 and python

Tags: python, opencv

I have image of a pdf page for which I want to separate paragraphs by drawing lines between them.
**The input is this:**
[image: Sample input image]

**The output I would want is this:**
[image: Output image]

What I have done so far using opencv is converting the image to binary, applying gaussian blur and dilating the image to get the following output:
[image]

The code is as follows:

```
img_path = r"C:\test\Samsung-file.JPG"
img_org = cv2.imread(img_path)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_org, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,11,30)

# Dilate to combine adjacent text contours
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,1))
dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=5)
```

Is there any method with which the lines can be drawn by identifying the space between white blocks(after dilation) ? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can look for the largest gaps in the horizontal projection of your dilated image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible solution: First, try to get a **segmentation mask** of the text. Apply an aggressive `dilation` operation with a big, nice, `rectangular structuring element`. The idea is to get **big blocks of text**, so we can clearly see the separating lines between them. Next, `reduce` the image to a `MAX` (`255`)  column, where every value is the **maximum** pixel value of each of the dilated images rows. If you invert the reduced image and find `contours`, you will get the space between the blocks of text you are looking for. Finally, get the average or middle point of the white spaces and draw a `line` at this vertical height.

Let's see the code:

```
# imports:
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Set image path
imagePath = "C://opencvImages//"
imageName = "PQZUL.jpg"

# Read image:
inputImage = cv2.imread(imagePath + imageName)
# Store a copy for results:
inputCopy = inputImage.copy()

# Convert BGR to grayscale:
grayInput = cv2.cvtColor(inputImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Threshold via Otsu
_, binaryImage = cv2.threshold(grayInput, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# Set kernel (structuring element) size:
kernelSize = (9, 9)

# Set operation iterations:
opIterations = 2

# Get the structuring element:
morphKernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, kernelSize)

# Perform Dilate:
dilateImage = cv2.morphologyEx(binaryImage, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, morphKernel, 
                               None, None, opIterations, cv2.BORDER_REFLECT101)
```

This set of operations gets you a nice segmentation mask, like this:

[image]

Now, reduce this image to a `MAX` column. This is the vertical reduction of the image:

```
# Reduce matrix to a n row x 1 columns matrix:
reducedImage = cv2.reduce(dilateImage, 1, cv2.REDUCE_MAX)

# Invert the reduced image:
reducedImage = 255 - reducedImage
```

This is the result - It is hard to see here, but the image has been reduced to just a column, where each value is the maximum pixel intensity value found for that particular image row:

[image]

Each white section is the "jump" of each text block to a new paragraph - these are the blobs (or `contours`) we are looking for. Let's find them and compute their `bounding boxes`:

```
# Find the big contours/blobs on the filtered image:
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Store the poly approximation and bound
contoursPoly = [None] * len(contours)
separatingLines = [ ]

# We need some dimensions of the original image:
imageHeight = inputCopy.shape[0]
imageWidth = inputCopy.shape[1]

# Look for the outer bounding boxes:
for i, c in enumerate(contours):

    # Approximate the contour to a polygon:
    contoursPoly = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 3, True)

    # Convert the polygon to a bounding rectangle:
    boundRect = cv2.boundingRect(contoursPoly)

    # Get the bounding rect's data:
    [x,y,w,h] = boundRect
```

So far we have the coordinates of the `bounding boxes`, we need to find a way to get the middle point of each vertical coordinate. There's a couple of solutions to this, I decide to just get the `height` of the bounding box and compute its middle coordinate. Here, still inside of the `for` loop:

```
    # Calculate line middle (vertical) coordinate,
    # Start point and end point:
    lineCenter = y + (0.5 * h)
    startPoint = (0,int(lineCenter))
    endPoint =  (int(imageWidth),int(lineCenter))

    # Store start and end points in list:
    separatingLines.append((startPoint, endPoint))

    # Draw the line:
    color = (0, 255, 0)
    cv2.line(inputCopy, startPoint, endPoint, color, 2)

    # Show the image:
    cv2.imshow("inputCopy", inputCopy)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I've stored the start and end points in the `separatingLines` list, so you can retrieve the data latter, if you need to. This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, This works well with the current document. For the documents with rotation I will need to draw horizontal lines, will the same work with minimum modification, or will it be a whole different approach. Any ideas?

Comment: @Sandeep It depends on the rotation angle. Due to the _image-to-column_ reduction I'm implementing here, the space between paragraphs could not be properly detected past a minimum rotation angle. What is needed is a perspective correction method. The most robust approach being [perspective warping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22656698/perspective-correction-in-opencv-using-python). If the perspective just exhibits 2D rotation, a compensation via [rotated rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18207181/opencv-python-draw-minarearect-rotatedrect-not-implemented) might suffice.