# OpenCV in python - enforce quadrilateral detection

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am searching for a particular closed (~) quadrilateral (a camera-phone photo of a sheet of A4 paper), because I would then like to warp it using e.g. the code at http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/25/4-point-opencv-getperspective-transform-example (which can't accept a polygon unless it has 4 sides).

In python, using `cv2.approxPolyDP()` gives for one photo extraction a 16-sided polygon, which is unsuitable for warping via the method above. Perhaps there is another way though.

I have tried running `cv2.approxPolyDP()` in a second pass but it doesn't help and I can't find a way to enforce a quadrilateral (which is nearly, but not quite, mentioned in other questions).

For the avoidance of doubt, a rectangle is only one special case of a quadrilateral.

Any ideas? Thanks!

**Edit:**

I didn't want to post the image or the code, because it's a general question, and I don't want a load of hand-tuned replies saying "algorithm x works on this image". But if you insist :\

Here's code to read the image below:

```
import cv2
image_src = cv2.imread('IieL8.jpg')
contours, _ =cv2.findContours(image_src,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
approxes=[]
for c in contours:
    approx=cv2.approxPolyDP(c,cv2.arcLength(c,True)*0.02,True)
    print approx.size
    approxes.append(approx)

# Do something with approximations
# print approxes
```

[image: Canny-detected input image]

Comment: Doesn't this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519545/automatic-perspective-correction-opencv

Comment: provide your code and the input image if you want help. you do not even mention the parameters you used for approxPolyDP(). also I don't see why you cannot simply get the 4 points you need from the polygon

Comment: @Piglet There you go. Now everyone can avoid answering the general question and give lots of specific advice.

Comment: you are free to ask general things but it always helps to provide detail. how do we know that you don't have 5 other things in your contour that do not belong to the card?  what about your epsilon? why is it so small?