# How to find x and y position from canny edge detection using OpenCV?

Tags: android, opencv, edge-detection

I am trying to find x and y position of image after convert from canny edge detection but i am unable to find accurate result. I am using opencvlibrary311.

Here is my code snippet.

```
// transformation matrix
Mat transformMatrix = Imgproc.getPerspectiveTransform(srcMat, dstMat);

finalMat = Mat.zeros((int) maxHeight, (int) maxWidth, CvType.CV_32FC2);
Imgproc.warpPerspective(rgbMat, finalMat, transformMatrix, finalMat.size());
Log.e("FinalDisplay", "finalMat: " + finalMat.size());

// display final results
Bitmap dstBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(finalMat.width(), finalMat.height(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
Log.e("FinalDisplay", "dstBitmap: " + img.getWidth() + " x " + img.getHeight());
Utils.matToBitmap(finalMat, dstBitmap); //convert mat to bitmap

// create cropped bitmap based on canny edge x and y and height and width
try {
    Bitmap crop = Bitmap.createBitmap(rotateandscalebitmap, cannyMat.rows(),cannyMat.cols(), dstBitmap.getWidth(), dstBitmap.getHeight()-20);
    // Bitmap crop = Bitmap.createBitmap(rotateandscalebitmap, ((int) horizontals.get(5)._center.y + 150), ((int) verticals.get(0)._center.x), dstBitmap.getWidth() + 100, dstBitmap.getHeight() + 10);

    croppedbitmap = crop;
    doRecognize(croppedbitmap);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I want this below output

[image]

Comment: Your code shows perspective transformation and cropping. What does Canny have to do with the question?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I want to detect rectangle card edges (4 sides) so canny return perfect edges of rectangle and I have crop card images from its edge. But I am not able to detect starting position (x) of edge as well as ending position (y) of edge.

Comment: I have added a image (I want this output).Thanks

Comment: The output is not that helpful without the input (and please blur out personal details even if they are yours). Is there any particular reason why you use Canny instead of contour detection or Hough transformation?

Comment: @user2986898 thanks for your suggestion. Can you please provide me demo code or any useful link regarding contour detection or Hough transformation?

Comment: Check the ones with 'contour' or 'hough' in their names.
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/d96/tutorial_py_table_of_contents_imgproc.html

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/da8/tutorial_table_of_content_imgproc.html

these are complete examples:
https://gist.github.com/cancan101/e19982815e4d3b2b3b95

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519545/automatic-perspective-correction-opencv

Please answer your question if/when you tackled this problem.

Comment: @user2986898 can you please provide me above code on android or java it will helpfull for me or any demo code on android if available on github or any other repository please give me link thanks in advance.