# opencv.js perspective transform

Tags: javascript, opencv

I'm trying to use opencv.js to find a document in a provided image (detect edges, apply perspective transform, etc.

I've got a reasonable set of code that (occasionally) detects edges of a document and grabs the bounding box for that.  However, I'm struggling to do the perspective transform steps.  There are some helpers for this (not in JS) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519545/automatic-perspective-correction-opencv/22550609#22550609) and [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/25/4-point-opencv-getperspective-transform-example/).

Unfortunately I'm getting stuck on something simple.  I can find the matching `Mat` that has 4 edges.  Displaying that shows it to be accurate.  However, I have no idea how to get some simple X/Y info out of that `Mat`.  I thought `minMaxLoc()` would be a good option, but I keep getting an error passing in my matching `Mat`.  Any idea why I can draw `foundContour` and get bounding box info from it, but I can't call `minMaxLoc` on it?

Code:

```
//<Get Image>
//<Convert to Gray, do GaussianBlur, and do Canny edge detection>
let contours = new cv.MatVector();
cv.findContours(matDestEdged, contours, hierarchy, cv.RETR_LIST, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

//<Sort resulting contours by area to get largest>

let foundContour = null;
for (let sortableContour of sortableContours) {
  let peri = cv.arcLength(sortableContour.contour, true);
  let approx = new cv.Mat();
  cv.approxPolyDP(sortableContour.contour, approx, 0.1 * peri, true);

  if (approx.rows == 4) {
    console.log('found it');
    foundContour = approx
    break;
  }
  else {
    approx.delete();
  }
}

//<Draw foundContour and a bounding box to ensure it's accurate>

//TODO: Do a perspective transform
let result = cv.minMaxLoc(foundContour);
```

The last line above results in a runtime error (`Uncaught (in promise): 6402256 - Exception catching is disabled`).  I can run `minMaxLoc()` on other `Mat` objects.

Comment: I don't fully understand it, but I found that the `foundContour` above is a 2-channel `Mat` object.  It seems `minMaxLoc` can only be called on single-channel `Mat`'s.  I'm not certain how to convert it, but I was able to get X/Y data out of the `foundContour.data32S[]` array.  There's likely a better way, but this as good as I've gotten at this point.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For anyone else looking to do this in OpenCV.JS, what I commented above seems to still be accurate.  The contour found can't be used with `minMaxLoc`, but the X/Y data can be pulled out of `data32S[]`.  That should be all that's needed to do this perspective transform.  Some code is below.

```
//Find all contours
let contours = new cv.MatVector();
let hierarchy = new cv.Mat();
cv.findContours(matDest, contours, hierarchy, cv.RETR_LIST, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

//Get area for all contours so we can find the biggest
let sortableContours: SortableContour[] = [];
for (let i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
  let cnt = contours.get(i);
  let area = cv.contourArea(cnt, false);
  let perim = cv.arcLength(cnt, false);

  sortableContours.push(new SortableContour({ areaSize: area, perimiterSize: perim, contour: cnt }));
}

//Sort 'em
sortableContours = sortableContours.sort((item1, item2) => { return (item1.areaSize > item2.areaSize) ? -1 : (item1.areaSize < item2.areaSize) ? 1 : 0; }).slice(0, 5);

//Ensure the top area contour has 4 corners (NOTE: This is not a perfect science and likely needs more attention)
let approx = new cv.Mat();
cv.approxPolyDP(sortableContours[0].contour, approx, .05 * sortableContours[0].perimiterSize, true);

if (approx.rows == 4) {
  console.log('Found a 4-corner approx');
  foundContour = approx;
}
else{
  console.log('No 4-corner large contour!');
  return;
}

//Find the corners
//foundCountour has 2 channels (seemingly x/y), has a depth of 4, and a type of 12.  Seems to show it's a CV_32S "type", so the valid data is in data32S??
let corner1 = new cv.Point(foundContour.data32S[0], foundContour.data32S[1]);
let corner2 = new cv.Point(foundContour.data32S[2], foundContour.data32S[3]);
let corner3 = new cv.Point(foundContour.data32S[4], foundContour.data32S[5]);
let corner4 = new cv.Point(foundContour.data32S[6], foundContour.data32S[7]);

//Order the corners
let cornerArray = [{ corner: corner1 }, { corner: corner2 }, { corner: corner3 }, { corner: corner4 }];
//Sort by Y position (to get top-down)
cornerArray.sort((item1, item2) => { return (item1.corner.y < item2.corner.y) ? -1 : (item1.corner.y > item2.corner.y) ? 1 : 0; }).slice(0, 5);

//Determine left/right based on x position of top and bottom 2
let tl = cornerArray[0].corner.x < cornerArray[1].corner.x ? cornerArray[0] : cornerArray[1];
let tr = cornerArray[0].corner.x > cornerArray[1].corner.x ? cornerArray[0] : cornerArray[1];
let bl = cornerArray[2].corner.x < cornerArray[3].corner.x ? cornerArray[2] : cornerArray[3];
let br = cornerArray[2].corner.x > cornerArray[3].corner.x ? cornerArray[2] : cornerArray[3];

//Calculate the max width/height
let widthBottom = Math.hypot(br.corner.x - bl.corner.x, br.corner.y - bl.corner.y);
let widthTop = Math.hypot(tr.corner.x - tl.corner.x, tr.corner.y - tl.corner.y);
let theWidth = (widthBottom > widthTop) ? widthBottom : widthTop;
let heightRight = Math.hypot(tr.corner.x - br.corner.x, tr.corner.y - br.corner.y);
let heightLeft = Math.hypot(tl.corner.x - bl.corner.x, tr.corner.y - bl.corner.y);
let theHeight = (heightRight > heightLeft) ? heightRight : heightLeft;

//Transform!
let finalDestCoords = cv.matFromArray(4, 1, cv.CV_32FC2, [0, 0, theWidth - 1, 0, theWidth - 1, theHeight - 1, 0, theHeight - 1]); //
let srcCoords = cv.matFromArray(4, 1, cv.CV_32FC2, [tl.corner.x, tl.corner.y, tr.corner.x, tr.corner.y, br.corner.x, br.corner.y, bl.corner.x, bl.corner.y]);
let dsize = new cv.Size(theWidth, theHeight);
let M = cv.getPerspectiveTransform(srcCoords, finalDestCoords)
cv.warpPerspective(matDestTransformed, finalDest, M, dsize, cv.INTER_LINEAR, cv.BORDER_CONSTANT, new cv.Scalar());
```

For reference, here is the class definition I was using for `SortableContour`.  The code above is meant as a guide, not as something that can run on its own, however.

```
export class SortableContour {
    perimiterSize: number;
    areaSize: number;
    contour: any;
  
    constructor(fields: Partial<SortableContour>) {
      Object.assign(this, fields);
    }
  }
```

Comment: what is `matDestTransformed` in this case? Is it original image source?

Comment: Bad name on my part.  Yes, that would be the image source that you want to process.  I took this from a chunk of other processing code, and in my case it was the output of another process (but an input into this one).

Comment: im getting an error on line with let sortableContours: sortableContour[] = [];  Error: Unexpected token :  ??

Comment: @NccWarp9 - I added my definition of that `SortableContour` type.  However, note that the code was meant as a guide that tells most of the story, not as a solution that runs on its own end-to-end.

Comment: I think there is a small mistake on the code new sortableContour should be new SortableContour

Comment: @BRass I figured out a lot using this. If possible, can you please shed some light on how did you get threshold_local from skimage.filters working for js.

Comment: I have tried your solution. However, I got the error on the line that define  sortableContours variable : let sortableContours: SortableContour[] = []; // SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'. Any working alternative would be appreciated.