# Name of this transformation? Geometric, Affine,

Tags: python, transformation, curve

I've been looking around the web and I cant seem to find the name for this specific transformation.
Basically I want to go from this:

[image: Bowling Lane - From behind view]

(don't mind the curve, it's only for presentation) to this:

[image: Bowling Lane - Above View].

The picture itself isn't necessary to transform because I can just use an already above view picture but what I want is to transform the curve from picture 1 so it would show it like it is in picture 2, because the entry angle of the curve hitting the pins on picture 1 isn't the same as the one shown on picture 2.

And what are the theoretical steps of doing this?
Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a homography?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is really a math question, not a programming question.

Comment: It really isn't, though. this is an English language question related to graphics programming. And a very common one, too: "I want to _program_ something, what is that something called so I can search for things that let me implement this". If anything, the recommendation should have been to ask this over on https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com, but it's still a programmer's question, and SO is fine. What wouldn't be fine is to send this person to math.stackexchange where they'll get yelled at for asking programming questions on a maths board.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring the pins entirely, because they'll just turn weird, what you're looking for is called [perspective control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_control), used to transform image data such that lines that "should" be parallel end up parallel, with "the thing you do" having quite a few names depending on how precise you want to get...

What you're looking for is...

1. a [colinear mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collineation) called
2. a [homographic transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography), but specifically
3. a [3d projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection), which is one of many
4. [anamorphic projections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anamorphosis)

Of those, (3) is going to get you all the programming details, whereas (1) and (2) will find you mathematical insight (*if* you can read the language of maths), and (4) will teach you about art.

And of course, because what you really want is python code to do this for you: you probably want to dig into SO posts like "[Automatic perspective correction OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519545/automatic-perspective-correction-opencv/22550609)" and related posts.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I can start looking around those keywords and implementing the code :)